# Rule for words/set of words that fit "Others with the same *"?

Tags: phrases, expressions

For example some words fit and feel aesthetic to read :

Others with the same *height*, Others with the same *marital status*, Others with the same *publisher*

While some words don't fit

Others with the same *location*, Others with the same *race*

Is it possible to formalize a rule using which we can use to identify these words?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your interpretation of 'fit' in the question. Can you clarify what you mean by this word in this context?

Comment: By fit, I meant aesthetic to read.
When anyone reads "Others with the same location", it feels off. I want to find out a reason for that. My intention is to then create a rule for it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the noun/phrase; it is with the preposition.

> "Others with the same location", it feels off

It is off. In the commonest contexts, it is "Others **in/at/near** the same location".

Likewise,

"Others with the same race." should be "Others **of** the same race."

There are no "rules" in English, there is only guidance; some guidance looks like a rule - it probably isn't.